# What is the meaning of 'cimode' in react-i18next and why isn't it properly documented?

Tags: react-i18next

I started using react-i18next a few days ago and I am very satisfied with it. However, I've been seeing this 'cimode' language here and there, in some posts and while debugging, but have no clue what it means. I've searched all over, I believe, and can't find any documentation on it.

In my particular case, I am generating some boilerplate code in a new website and created a demo page to show how to use localization in the website. I am generating toggle language buttons from the languages I set on the whitelist and, to my surprise, I have a 'cimode' button. I know I can filter it out and I will, but I would like to know what it should be used for and maybe to see better documentation for it in https://react.i18next.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my understanding, CIMODE is used for testing to consistently return the translation key instead of the variant value.

[It seems rather hidden on the FAQ](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/faq#process).

Comment: Thanks Seth, I had the feeling that was it, but wasn't 100% sure. In my code I have a custom hook that returns an init function. I am mocking that in my test's so react18next doesn't even initialize. I am also mocking the "t" return fro useTranslation to essentially do what  CIMODE those.
But when the code runs locally, is there any way to exclude CIMODE from the whitelisted languages?